# How can I combine my social networking feeds with RSS feeds (such as new questions on WebApps) in a single timeline?

Tags: twitter, rss, facebook-timeline

With so many different ways to get information on the web (twitter, facebook, myspace, RSS, etc.), I would like to combine them into one place rather than having to run different tools or visit different web sites. Is there a client (web-based or otherwise) that can combine these varying information sources into a single timeline? Preferrably, this would also allow me to update my own status and to respond to items.

Comment: There's no standard - at least, no widely accepted standard - for responding to items on all the different information sources you'd be aggregating. So no single application can give you that capability for all sources. The best I would hope for is an RSS reader that allows you to leave comments on the best-known blog sites like Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

You can add all of your social sites activity in a single timeline using websites like [Google Buzz](http://www.google.com/buzz) ([now retired](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1698228?hl=en-GB)) or [Friendfeed](http://www.friendfeed.com/) and respond to some of them (for example you can reply to tweets in Friendfeed).

Comment: Are you able to follow people not on friendfeed?

Comment: The question asks how to aggregate rss/atom feeds in with the rest.  How do you get friendfeed to follow an atom feed (like recent webapps questions)?  Wikipedia says it can do so, but I don't see it in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

If your sources of information are RSS or Atom based or have RSS or Atom feeds available then you can use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to combine them into a single feed.

Comment: Shevek: Does Pipes allow me to respond to items in my own status?

Comment: I don't think so - it merely merges the RSS/Atom feeds into a single RSS feed

Answer (score 2):

I use [threadsy](http://threadsy.com) to combine a whole lot of streams into a single timeline. [Silentale](http://silentale.com/) is another such option

Comment: Sathya: Do these allow me to post status updates and responses?

Comment: @Jeff threadsy does. Silentale is read-only AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) and subscribe to RSS for each of those sites mentioned.  That's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Can I reply to items using Google Reader?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking try [net vibes](http://www.netvibes.com). This site is really well designed.  Just select the social network dashboard and you will be given the opertunity to customise modules (what they call wigets).